# A runnable .jar file with libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable, libraries

Want to warn you, that I have been tinkering around the site for some minutes and didn't find any suitable answers.
So, my question is -
 What certainly, step by step, should I do from having the code done in Eclipse to make an executable program even on other PC's?
I'm using Eclipse, JRE7.
I have tried that before, but that executable .jar worked just on my PC.

I heard about keeping the .jar with lib files, but have no more ideas about that. Your help would help a lot.

You have my anticipated thanks.
I have 4 class-files in my project located in the "src" folder.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error when you try this on another machine? Can you post it here?

Comment: Sorry, if I was unclear.

Comment: I'm usually creating a runable .jar file and tring to execute it on other PC's. Executing directly by clicking and getting the error "Java exception occured".

Comment: But the application is working well on my PC, on the other hand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer 1. if you are new to eclipse, then i guess your having trouble exporting a simple program that has no dependencies. to export a program follow these steps:

1. right click on your main project folder. click export
2. under java, choose jar file, not executable jar file.
3. on the first page you need to specify an output file. do so.
4. the next thing (i think) is asking you to make a javadoc or something. skip it
5. the next is the important one, so listen carefully. the first thing it asks is for you to make a meta inf file. you can or you can not. it will save sdome time later if you do make one.
6. the step will also ask you for your main class file. click browse and you should be prompted with some of your class files. the class you choose should be the class with your main `public static void main(String[] args){}` method. this method is critical so if you do not have it for some reason, you need to learn more about it.
7. click export and you should be done!

answer 2. your have the exported file but you need some dependencies like lwjgl for example. you are a more advanced coder and not new if this is your problem. it it is, go download [jarmatey](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jarmatey&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticvoidgames.com%2FSvgExe%2F&ei=lvVkVJ_cCc6cyASq0IDwBg&usg=AFQjCNEJTqiCNnfD7V5gjlnk8oNhjaKzxQ&bvm=bv.79189006,d.aWw) and learn how to use it. there is other programs that do this too but i prefer this one.

Comment: also make sure all of your links to files are working ;)

Comment: Hello. Thank you very much for the response. To be certain: When selectin resorces to export (3 step) There is a check box :
1) Export generated files and res
2) Export all output folders for checked projects
3) Export Java source files and resources
4) Export refactorings for checked projects

Which one to select?

Comment: i guess the first one. im at school so i cant remember which one i use but, i think the 3rd one exports exerything including your source code so you dont usually want to use that one. the first or second should be fine

Comment: Now, when I have this .jar file - how to make it runable? Do I need anything else to include?
Or I just need to download this JarMatey and create the runable jar?

Comment: jarmatey is only if you are using other jar files with your program. you should be able to just double click it

Comment: But this is a simple .jar file, I can't just run it by double clicking, or can I?

Comment: you say your using a librarie. which one?

Comment: I'm not using any library. I have made all the listed steps, like you said.

Comment: you should be able to just double click it then. you do not need jarmatey

Comment: So I have exported all the crap and now I have a jar file on the desktop. Let me look again, maybe I have done something wrong.

Comment: choosing your main class if a big part of the exporting process. dont forget to do that if you did. also if you want, try the code from here and when you export it make this the main class to make sure its not just your program. [link](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JFramewithLabelandWindowListenertoHandleClosingtheFrame.htm) btw i had the same problem when i started coding java too thats why im helping

Comment: The main class is Interface (since I have an interface in my program, so this is right)
By the way, I can run it from cmd with "java -jar *Name*.jar

Comment: is it a program that runs in the console? java doesnt automatically open the console when you double click a program

Comment: Nope, I'm starting the console and typing the command manually. The jar file does nothing when clicked.

Comment: i mean does the program you made open up any windows or anything? what does your program do basically

Comment: This is a database with a interface (JFrame).
Nothing happens, no windows, no files created (they should have been created).

Comment: its probably your code. try my earlier comment with the link.

Comment: Thank you very much for help, Tyler. I created a .exe app with Launch4j and it worked even on other PC's!

Comment: jar files work on pc. the only reason i would turn a jar file into an exe is if you want to put it up for the general public since because when you download a jar file it will say its a virus and if its an exe it wont even if its the same program. just a tip :)